# Using syntax highlight from GitHub

Tags: html, github, syntax-highlighting

What syntax highlighting is used on GitHub (for HTML, CSS, JavaScript, C#) when viewing source code-file and **is it available for the public to use**?

It works on the page and it works when embedding on a page (from a Gist), like this:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/1009439.js"></script>
```

But can I just include their JavaScript-library and let it highlight my code?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Github uses [pygments](http://pygments.org/) to highlight syntax. Pygments is running on the server, instead of a pure Javascript client solution. If you're looking for a Javascript solution [check out this review](http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2011/05/22/highlighters-comparison/) of the various options.

Comment: The funny thing is though GitHub uses pygments, pygments doesn't use GitHub. They're on Bitbucket

Comment: Could that be because they used Pygments from the get go when creating Github? Which would mean that Pygments would have to have been hosted elsewhere considering Github did not yet exist.

Comment: Github no longer uses pygments. It now uses a Ruby package called "Linguist" that can process TextMate-compatible highlighting grammers, See https://github.com/github/linguist

Answer (score 21):

According to [this help page](https://help.github.com/articles/my-repository-is-marked-as-the-wrong-language/), GitHub currently highlights syntax with the open-source [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) library for Ruby. Linguist highlights each language using the `tmLanguage` files linked in [`vendor/grammars`](https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/vendor/grammars).

Since Linguist is written in Ruby, it can only be used on the server. If you want a client-side JavaScript library that you can just include on a page, you will have to [find a different library](https://www.google.com/search?q=JavaScript+syntax+highlighter).

Answer (score 5):

According to this: http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/github-git-repository-hosting

they are using [Python Pygments](http://pygments.org/)

> Chris Wanstrath shared some
>   information about the inner workings
>   of GitHub with InfoQ:
>
> GitHub is mostly implemented in Rails.
>   The post-commit integration mini-apps
>   we're working on are all written in
>   Merb, we use the Python Pygments for
>   syntax highlighting, and we use Ara T.
>   Howard's Bj plus some Ruby scripts for
>   our queueing system. And, of course,
>   we use the Ruby Grit library to
>   interface with Git.

Comment: Pygments is used by a bunch of things, including Trac.  It's cool.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they use their [albino](https://github.com/github/albino) gem. It is a Ruby wrapper for the pygments syntax highlighter.

Here is an article of a comparison I read recently on javascript based syntax highlighters (if that is what you need): http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2011/05/22/highlighters-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

As others have said previously, GitHub uses [Pygments](http://pygments.org/). You can achieve the same effect by using it together with [pygments-style-github](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygments-style-github).